Что нужно указать в опции «Config or installation directory», вместо «Do not import settings», используя среду разработки Intellij IDEA?
При настройке параметров Intellij IDEA мне непонятно, что следует указать в опции: «Config or installation directory»:

Сначала я исследовал этот тип вопроса, проверяя учебные пособия, например:

IntelliJ IDEA Tutorial - How to Install and Configure [2020]
IntelliJ IDEA Beginner Tutorial | Download and Setup
How to Setup settings.xml for Intellij and Maven Project | Intellij | Maven
How to Install IntellijIDEA with Java 18 on Windows 10
Configure your intelliJ project
IntelliJ IDEA Tutorial
How to install IntelliJ IDEA on Windows 10/11 (64 bit) [ 2023 Update ] Java 19
JetBrains change location of config and system directories

также проверил статьи следующего формата:

Installing IntelliJ IDEA
IntelliJ configuration directory
Directories used by the IDE

и пришел к выводу, что в пути следует указать конфигурационный файл idea.properties:
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5\bin\idea.properties

Дословно говорится, что:

В IntelliJ IDEA конфигурационные файлы и настройки, используемые самой
IDE, обычно находятся в папке "bin". В этой папке содержатся файлы,
которые могут включать в себя:
idea.properties: файл для настройки свойств JVM и других параметров
среды. idea.vmoptions или idea64.vmoptions: файл для настройки опций
виртуальной машины Java.

Но я всё ещё сбиваюсь с толку, потому что ни один из предоставленных источников выше не отвечает прямо на мой вопрос, игнорируя полностью этот вариант как альтернативу.
Я ищу любую официальную информацию (желательно) из любой документации, что мне следует указать в опции «Config or installation directory», если я не хочу настраивать через опцию «Do not import settings».
И почему конкретно этот конфигурационный файл следует использовать в пути?
Чтобы уточнить:
Вариант "Do not import settings" я в данном случае вообще не рассматриваю, потому что не хочу использовать конфигурацию по умолчанию, а хочу выбрать вручную опцию, которая применялась в одной из проверенных мною старых версий, которыми я уже пользовался.
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Директория с конфигами обычно лежит по пути:
~\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\ для Win.
Проверить папку, где лежат Ваши конфигурации в "старой" версии можно зайдя в:
File | Manage IDE Settings, тут можно сделать экспорт конфигов и загрузить их в новой версии или через import посмотреть директорию с конфигами.
Вот документация про конфиги:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings
